# Criar um algoritmo que remova e adicione um item

Tags: php, html

Estou elaborando um código meio complexo, então só vou passar o necessário.
 Basicamente estou tentando criar um algoritmo no php que simula um inventário de videogame, onde podemos equipar itens no personagem, e removê-los depois. para garantir que os itens estão equipados e desequipados, eu fiz esse código:

```
if($equip == 0) {
    if($sword == 1) {
        $damage = $damage+3; 
        $weapon = 'Sword'; $sword=3;
    } elseif($sword == 2 && $setweapon == 1) {
        $damage = $damage-3;
        $sword = 3;
    } 

    if($plate == 1) {
        $defense = $defense+3; 
        $armor = "Chestplate"; 
        $plate = 3;
    } elseif($plate == 2) {
        $defense = $defense-3; 
        $plate = 3;
    }

    if($staff == 1) {
        $damage = $damage+1;
        $mana = $mana+15; 
        $weapon = 'Staff'; 
        $staff = 3;
    } elseif($sword == 2 && $setweapon == 0){
        $damage = $damage-1;
        $mana = $mana-15;
        $staff = 3;
    }

    if($cape == 1) {
        $defense = $defense+2;
        $mana = $mana+15;
        $armor = 'Cape';
        $cape = 3;
    } elseif($cape == 2) {
        $defense = $defense-2;
        $mana = $mana-15; 
        $cape = 3;
    }

    if($bow == 1) {
        $damage = $damage+2; 
        $distance = $distance+2; 
        $weapon = 'Bow'; 
        $bow = 3;
    } elseif($bow == 2 && $setweapon == 0) {
        $damage = $damage-2; 
        $distance = $distance-2; 
        $bow = 3;
    }

    if($vest == 1) {
        $dextery = $dextery+15;
        $defense = $defense+2; 
        $armor = 'Vest'; 
        $vest = 3;
    } elseif($vest == 2) {
        $dextery = $dextery-15;
        $defense = $defense-2; 
        $vest = 3;
    }

    $equip = 1;
}
```

Tudo bem, isso funciona bem para quando o jogo inicia e equipa isso automaticamente de acordo com a classe do personagem. Minha intenção é tentar fazer um pequeno menu, onde eu escolho um item que estiver com o número 3 (Os itens de número 3 apareceriam no meu inventário) e transformo ele para 1, equipando no meu personagem.
Mas como eu irei identificar esse item que será equipado no html?

Comment: Já estudou classes?

Comment: Sendo franco, não conheço

Comment: Acabei de ver o que são classes. Eu tentei usar classes no C# e não funcionou (assim como todo o meu código), não vou usar classes no meu código(complicado demais para o meu nível).

Comment: Na minha opinião, sua pergunta **como um todo** dificilmente vai ter uma resposta adequada. Se algo breve lhe for suficiente: crie um link no HTML com uma query string (`index.php?item_id=1234`) apontando o ID do tal item. Daí no PHP você obtém esse id via GET: `$_GET['item_id']`. Acredito que além disso vai tornar sua pergunta fora de escopo do site. 

Comment: e como eu faço uma query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que você não quer utilizar classes, você pode estruturar seus objetos com *arrays*.

Cada jogador deve ter um nome, atributos básicos e um inventário. Itens que estão equipados também estão no inventário do jogador, então para diferenciar basta ter uma *flag* no item que define se está equipado ou não.

```
$woss = [
    'name' => 'Woss',
    'title' => 'Lord of the Universe',
    'stats' => [
        'life' => 100,
        'energy' => 100,
        'stamina' => 100,
        'strength' => 5,
        'defense' => 3
    ],
    'items' => []
];
```

Neste caso `items` será uma lista de *arrays* que definem os items. Um item deve possuir um nome e os atributos. Por exemplo, uma espada aumenta os atributos de ataque; uma parte da armadura aumenta atributos de defesa.

```
$excaliburSword = [
    'name' => 'Excalibur Sword',
    'equipped' => false,
    'stats' => [
        'strength' => 4
    ]
];

$dragonPants = [
    'name' => 'Dragon Pants',
    'equipped' => false,
    'stats' => [
        'defense' => 7
    ]
];
```

Para manipular os dados você cria funções - muitas funções, use e abuse. Por exemplo, vamos criar uma função que adiciona um item no inventário de um jogador:

```
function player_add_item(&$player, $item) {
    $player['items'][] = $item;
}
```

Assim, poderíamos adicionar a espada no inventário do jogador:

```
print_r($woss);

player_add_item($woss, $excaliburSword);
```

O jogador ficaria:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Woss
    [title] => Lord of the Universe
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [life] => 100
            [energy] => 100
            [stamina] => 100
            [strength] => 5
            [defense] => 3
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Excalibur Sword
                    [equipped] => false
                    [stats] => Array
                        (
                            [strength] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Para equipar um item bastaria você criar uma função que altera o valor de `equipped` do item para `true`; para remover você poderia criar uma função que remove o item do *array*; para calcular os atributos do jogador considerando os itens equipados você poderia criar uma função que soma os atributos equipados aos atributos do jogador; etc.